# How to stub functions that are called when a controller is created?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a number of functions that are called when a controller is created - I need to stub these to prevent them running, but I can't because the controller hasn't been created yet - a chicken/egg situation. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Move creation of controller to the `it` section after stubbing / mocking dependencies

Comment: If you use angular 1.5 components you can use $onInit() in your controller. $onInit has to be called manually in unit tests which make the instantiation logic easy to stub.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for - thanks once more Amygdaloideum :)